# How to install MySQL 5.7 on CentOS 9?

Tags: centos, mysql

I have an use case where I need to install MySQL 5.7 on CentOS 9. I found a [guide](https://computingforgeeks.com/install-mysql-5-7-on-centos-rhel-linux/) which describes how to do this on CentOS 8, and it works perfectly. However, when I try the same steps on CentOS 9, it gives an error.

Below is the repo file which I inserted as per the guide.

**/etc/yum.repos.d/mysql-community.repo**

```
[mysql57-community]
name=MySQL 5.7 Community Server
baseurl=http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-5.7-community/el/7/$basearch/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0

[mysql-connectors-community]
name=MySQL Connectors Community
baseurl=http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-connectors-community/el/7/$basearch/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0

[mysql-tools-community]
name=MySQL Tools Community
baseurl=http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-tools-community/el/7/$basearch/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
```

Then I ran this command:

```
sudo dnf install mysql-community-server
```

This command gives the below error.

```
Error: 
 Problem: package mysql-community-server-5.7.40-1.el7.x86_64 requires mysql-community-client(x86-64) >= 5.7.9, but none of the providers can be installed
.......
.......
```

MySQL 5.7 is not in CentOS / RHEL 8 AppStream repository as well. However, the above method worked on CentOS 8. Therefore, I feel this method should work on CentOS 9 as well. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: You don't.

Long answer: Get the srpm and build it yourself.

Longer answer: Find someone who has already built it for EL9.

It seems only 8.0 is built officially for EL9. And you got lucky, somehow with installing an EL7 package on EL8

Answer (score 0):

I know this is (at the time of this message) a 7 month old question... but I found myself in a similar situation, where I would like to install **MySQL 5.7 on RHEL/Centos 9**. I hope my answer will help people that are looking to accomplish that.

If you don't like to go to the way where you compile from sources yourself, and want precompiled packages, you can use the packages from Percona. They have them available for download and also in their repo. Here are the links:

[Percona download page](https://www.percona.com/downloads)

[Installing Percona Server for MySQL 5.7 on RHEL/Centos](https://docs.percona.com/percona-server/5.7/installation/yum_repo.html)

Comment: Hello @RohitGupta. Thank you for your feedback. But I would like to assure I have no interest in promote anything. The comment is just my pure experience over time with Percona, from the time of MySQL 5.5 until now, which is a quite long time. The packages they provide are free to use, no need to register or anything. If there are any doubts about the validity of my proposed solution here, would invite anyone interested to test it. I am sure the result would speak for itself.